# Running EmojiOneJava on NetBeans

Tags: java, javafx, emoji, emojione

I keep running into errors when I try to run the code from EmojiOneJava on NetBeans. It's someone else's code and I want to see how it'll work.
I need help either running this code in NetBeans or via GitBash (I used a Windows computer)

Link to GitHub repository: https://github.com/UltimateZero/EmojiOneJava

Example of error I encounter:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at com.uz.emojione.fx.EmojiListExample.start(EmojiListExample.java:24)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
```

Exception running application com.uz.emojione.fx.EmojiListExample
Java Result: 1

Comment: The error means the `FXMLLoader` can't find the FMXL file. Probably the FXML didn't get deployed when you built the application. Make sure the resources folder is configured as a build folder (I am not a NetBeans user; I don't know how that is configured in NetBeans....).

Comment: He changed his file structure. His `FXML` file is in a folder name `resources`.

Comment: If you follow my instruction below, your code will run. I got it to run. You still have a problem. You try to load the images but your paths to the images are incorrect. Just like your paths to the `FXML` files are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First:

Refactor both of your `FXML` files into the `fx` folder with their controllers. Do the same thing with `emoji.json`and `Json.java`. Refactor those to the `emojione` folder.

[image: New Project Structure]

> Second:

```
//The correct way to load and Image:


private String getEmojiImagePath(String hexStr)
{
    String filePath = "resources/com/uz/emojione/fx/png_40/" + hexStr + ".png";
    File file = new File(filePath);

    return file.toURI().toString();
}
```

> Third:

Go to your `src` folder and cut the `resources` folder. Now paste the `resources` folder into the same folder as `src`

[image]

> Finally:
>   You will have to deploy the `resources` folder in the same folder as your `jar` to run this outside of Netbeans.

[image]

> I notice that you also have this:

[image]

To get this running I had to do the same thing with loading the images that I did above.